# Vue.js add component option (prop) using custom directive

Tags: vue.js

I have `Custom` component using my own directive (`v-color`):

```html
<custom v-color="color" />
```

And my script, which I define `this.color` and `this.changeColor()`:

```js
{
   data () {
     return {
       color: red
     }
   },

   methods: {
     changeColor (color) {
       this.color = color
     }
   }
}
```

**How can I write the code of `v-color` directive to change `v-bind:color` of `<custom />`?**

In other words, the value of `v-bind:color` will be `red` when the component is loaded. If `this.color` is modified by a method (such as `this.changeColor('blue')`), value of `v-bind:color` would be auto-updated.

I would appreciate solutions that avoid "watch", because I will use `v-color` many times.

Comment: Is `v-color` a prop? If it is, color would be reactive doing `<custom :v-color="color" />`

Comment: It is a directive.

Comment: shouldn't `date` be `data`

Comment: Thanks, @DerekPollard. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this seems to fit what you're looking for:

```js
Vue.component('third-party-component', {
  props: ['color'],
  template: '<div :style="{ color }" v-cloak>{{color}}</div>'
});

Vue.component('hoc-component', {
  props: ['color'],
  computed: {
    transformedColor () {
      if (this.color === "blu") return "blue";
      if (this.color === "re") return "red";
      if (this.color == "or") return "orange";
      if (this.color == "pur") return "purple";
      return this.color;
    }
  },
  template: '<third-party-component  :color="transformedColor" />'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app" v-cloak>
    <div>
      <hoc-component color="blu"></hoc-component>
      <hoc-component color="or"></hoc-component>
      <hoc-component color="re"></hoc-component>
      <hoc-component color="pur"></hoc-component>
      <hoc-component color="pink"></hoc-component>
      <hoc-component color="green"></hoc-component>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we are taking advantage of the Higher Order Component pattern in order to modify the data we need and pass it on to the third party component. This is a much more effective way of mutating and handling data change without the side effects that directives have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `el.style.color` is not `v-bind:color`.

Comment: @CaioTarifa so you want to bind data to the component and you don't want to use the built in `:color="color"` ?

Comment: Yes, I need to bind `color` prop using directive instead of normal binding.

Comment: @CaioTarifa mind saying why exactly? Sounds like you're trying to circumvent using something like global state. Also not sure why you don't like watch

Comment: I put here in StackOverflow just a simple use case.

Basically, my directive will act as an intermediary between a third party component and my code. A simple example to understand would be: in my code I have "red", but the component needs to get "redist" in the `v-bind:color`, so the directive will add "ist" at the end by a transparent way.

About avoiding "watch": If I have to use v-color in a thousand different places, I would not want to have a thousand "watches".

Comment: @CaioTarifa - wouldn't a HOC be better than a directive? You take in the data you want from props then mutate and pass it along to the third part component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191051/discussion-between-caio-tarifa-and-derek-pollard).

Comment: Just a feedback, @Derek. Your solution is great, but is does not work 100%  (in my use case) because of the third-party component depends by a correct `this.$parent`.

Comment: @CaioTarifa ahh - you'd have to pass along the methods that the third party component emits to the parent (HOC) onto the outer parent of the HOC